# can I build boost libraries with std::shared_ptr instead of boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

In c++11 project I would like to use as much as possible stl primitives instead the boost ones. I though still need some of the boost libraries - for example filesystem. It though uses boost::shared_ptr.

My question is - is there a way to make boost to switch to using std::shared_ptr and how?

Comment: Why would you want to change the internals of boost? Use `std::shared_ptr` in your code and let boost use whatever it needs.

Comment: Is it internal? There are no interfaces of any library that expect or return shared_ptr?

Comment: @gsf: Functions take/return a `shared_ptr` only if they are transferring ownership of an object. Very few Boost libraries actually need to claim ownership of something the user passes in. So most parameters are either value types, references, or naked (non-owning) pointers. Indeed, I can't think of a Boost function offhand that uses `shared_ptr` in an interface.

Comment: @NicolBolas This makes sense, I cannot too, but I haven't used boost filesystem extensively before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Boost have a configuration setting to make it use `std::shared_ptr`? Not generally. Boost.Asio [apparently has a way to make the internals use `std::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/shared_ptr.html) (which seems to turn on automatically when `std::shared_ptr` is available). But there is no Boost-wide setting for this.

You could probably do some find-replace gymnastics to make it work. Of course, that assumes that none of those Boost libraries are making assumptions about Boost's internals. And that none of them have access to its internals. And that `boost::shared_ptr` has no interface differences from `std::shared_ptr`.

It's not going to be worth the effort. Let Boost use whatever code it wants to internally. The only place where it should matter to you is in interfaces, and very few Boost libraries actually use `boost::shared_ptr` in an interface to your code. Indeed, I did a Google site search for `std::shared_ptr` on the Boost 1.59 documentation, and the only place that I found that it was even referenced was in the document I linked above.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you do not do a find and replace of boost shared_ptr with std shared_ptr. Boost's shared_ptr is a strong superset of the C++ 11 shared_ptr, indeed the C++ 1y shared_ptr is expected to become much more like the Boost one. Boost uses the C++ 1y extensions, so it isn't going to be a straight swap.

Comment: @NiallDouglas: What is C++1y? Are you talking about C++14 or C++17 or what?

Comment: Yes you're right, I meant C++1z apologies. That is "C++ 17", though of course any improved shared_ptr won't land as part of 1z, but rather as some proposed Libraries TS around the same time.